# How to nest xaml.cs under xaml files when using wildcards in csproj

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I have a question regarding the csproj file.

As I have a big source base that is generated, I am trying to minimize collisions on the project file (when developing with a team).

I managed to get rid of most collisions by using tags like this:

```
<Compile Include="Services\**\*.cs" />
```

for normal cs files and

```
<Page Include="Entities\**\*.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
```

for xaml and codebehind.

Unfortunately, I loose the grouping of .xaml and .xaml.cs pairs, which is bearable but clumsy.

Is there any way to create a generic pattern for these?

```
<Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

I know about the possibility to split the csproj itself but this would forbid solution wide searches so this is a no-go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using MSBuild 15's static update syntax, you can do

```
 <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
```

The trick here is that MSbuild separates the path into `Filename` (`foo.xaml.cs` => `foo.xaml`) and `Extension` (`foo.xaml.cs` => `.cs`), so `%(Filename)` can be used to reference the xaml file.

Comment: Not for Framework, apparently.  (Available only for .NET Core projects in Visual Studio 2017 or later.) :( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022 but still +1 ... wait, VS2019 seems to be ok with in in .NET 4.8 Winforms. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

> As I have a big source base that is generated

Can't you generate, or at least update, the `csproj` file too?

That is what I do for a 99% generated assembly. I put all manual work in a separate folder, which is enumerated in the generator and added to the project file next to the generated items.

Comment: Surely I can do (and did) this, but I get conflicts when team-mates do the same.

Comment: Usually you can merge that away pretty easy as long as the order doesn't change (so make sure to sort uniformly), or hit the generate button again (maybe even as an before build event in Visual Studio).

Comment: As in general wildcards are supported, I would rather see the two files than to fix dependencies in the csproj ;-))